# various inline-block display problems

Tags: css

I have a simple design for my lists, with simple images, like :

```
<div class="image_list_tick">

  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

The CSS is :

```
.image_list_tick ul {
  list-style-image: url('green-tick2.gif');
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I tried that code in chrome and firefox and got weirdly different results.

FIREFOX :

[image: FIREFOX CASE 1]

[image: FIREFOX CASE 2]

The second one is what i would actually want to happen. Now, in chrome i also get this :

CHROME :

[image: CHROME CASE 1]

Note, the list itself should be centered in the middle of that page, even though it's not shown in the above images. The point is to have the list in the center.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What does inline-block have to do with it? Why not just leave display at default?

Comment: i would think the same, but if the text where this list is included is center aligned (text-align center), then the results are like the one on Chrome and what's more the 'ticks' stay in the left site (like float left), while the text stays in the center, as expected

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the code you provided (slightly modified): http://jsfiddle.net/NbS3h/. I'd need more context to figure out why that's happening to your list images. Can you show us the rest of the HTML and CSS?

Comment: Yea, I would definitely check this thing out with Firebug to see what other css is given to the `li`'s ..and/or `ul`.

Comment: @peterjmag : Check here http://jsfiddle.net/E4MTg/1/

Comment: i think it's some external class css selector that gets inherited by the list as well, and causes this effect.

Comment: text-align: left fixes it, but also moves it to the left of the div, while i want it in the center.

Comment: Here's what I see in Chrome: http://i.imgur.com/ZXHOf.png. Is it doing something else for you?

Comment: Yes, that's what i see as well, but it's not what i want of course :) The ticks should stick with the text and not float left. They do with inline-block, but not in all cases.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't realize that you wanted the images to stagger like that, rather than sitting flush left. Try `list-style-position: inside`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NbS3h/1/.

Comment: This is what i already have though :) Check the images. I want an effect like the second image. Simple aligned.

Comment: Yes, but you also want it centered. In which case just tell yourself in words what you want: "I want the list itself to be centered, but I want every list item to be aligned to the left". Which is exactly the solution (see the latest comments on my answer).

Comment: which is why i selected your answer :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Remove the `display: inline-block`. It's probably what causing it to go haywire. Also, there may be other (probably general) styles that affect your list. Use firebug or chrome developer tools to investigate it.</s>

You want to do the following: "Keep the list aligned in the center of the page, but keep the list **items** aligned to the left of the **list itself**. Therefore, this [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/E4MTg/4)  should be what you want. Code used (simplified):

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    list-style-image: url('http://i779.photobucket.com/albums/yy80/000jericho/tick_green_big.gif'); /* random tick mark I found */
    display: inline-block;
}
li {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Follow K.I.S.S and you should be fine.

**[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/E4MTg/4)**

Comment: i guess the problem is that this text-align is inherited by an external text-align:center declaration

Comment: @SpyrosP Then just add `.image_list_tick ul { text-align: left; }`Though you might want to consider removing that general `text-align: center;`Because most often you'd want to have text aligned left rather than center..

Comment: @Lollero, check the comments in the question :P Also, i need to align the text to the center lol :P

Comment: @Truth, check the comments in the question as well please. Overriding is not really an option.

Comment: I have to make sure that the text is aligned in the center BUT the list also shows fine.

Comment: @SpyrosP both chrome and firefox show this one fine: http://jsfiddle.net/E4MTg/2/

Comment: Yeah, but now ? :) http://jsfiddle.net/E4MTg/3/ Different in the two browsers and both wrong.

Comment: @SpyrosP People have been giving solutions to get what your second example image shows, but you keep saying it's not what you want.. so I'm surely confused.

Comment: @Lollero : There is no solution yet, if you have one show it please. What i want is the effect on the second image where the list is on a center aligned text.

Comment: @SpyrosP You need to do some serious elaborating because the jsfiddle in this answer is _exactly_ the same as what your second example image looks like.

Comment: @SpyrosP Now I understood your question. See http://jsfiddle.net/E4MTg/4/ and tell me if that's what you wanted.

Comment: @SpyrosP Poor example images. You should've put borders around the images and said that the border represents the viewport or the parent element. Because now that I selected your second example image I noticed that the list is centered in the image document..

Comment: @Truth : Awesome, nice idea to align the <li>s. Great one, works like a charm !